# My Meta-Description is 146 characters long and is truncated on Google

Tags: seo, meta-tags

My website has a **146 characters long** description and was truncated by google.

**The description is the following:**

"BETA-CRET PROMERA HEALTH: Conheça e compre aqui o BETA-CRET. O mais poderoso pré-treino do mundo. BETA-CRET, os treinos mais intensos da sua vida."

**Google is showing this:**

"BETA-CRET PROMERA HEALTH: Conheça e compre aqui o BETA-CRET. O mais poderoso pré-treino do mundo. BETA-CRET, os treinos mais intensos da sua ..."

Any idea on what may have happened?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is off-topic here. (This is not an SEO site; it's a site for programming and programmer's tools questions.) The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has information on the types of questions that should be asked here. Keeping questions on-topic keeps down noise and clutter and helps keep SO a useful programming resource. Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: Ok, didn't know about that. Sorry Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's [meta-description policy](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35624) states (emphasis mine):

> Google will **sometimes** use the meta description of a page in search results snippets, **if we think it gives users a more accurate description** than would be possible purely from the on-page content.

They might not display the entire description - or any of the description at all - depending on what their heuristics say about your site. The easiest solution might be to shorten your description, but it's still not guaranteed that Google will display it all. SEO is not an exact science!